# Can I route my mailgun email to S3 bucket and save data there?

Tags: amazon-s3, mailgun

I have a requirement where I need to fetch email data and save somewhere. I can route it to my server and save the data there. Is there any feature where the email data can be routed to an S3 Bucket and I save the data there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you need a backend app that recursively fetch your emails using the Mailgun API formatted as json, then you can save these as text files on S3 service that can be queried later by another backend application.

It requires programming and a server infrastructure.

Regards,